# 10.04 notification area wireless notification wrong

Tags: 10.04, wireless, ubuntu-netbook, notification-area

I just installed 10.04 on my hp mini 110. All worked out of the box except the wireless (as expected), so I followed the plethora of forum posts and installed/activated the STA driver. This worked and I am connected to the Internet but the wireless notification shows the red exclamation point over the wireless notification anyway...does anyone know how to fix this to show the correct notification?

Also, after installing the broadcom-sta-common package I did not uninstall any packages (I read several places about blacklisting or uninstalling the b43/ssb drivers). So are there any unnecessary packages I should remove from synaptic due to installing the STA packages?

Thank you for any advice in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the system kernel doesn't work with your wifi firmware. Try it to make a hosyap,
and compile the two into the kernel.

It's a hell of a job.

First install the newest driver and firmware in Windows.

You can check the compatibility from the wifi chipset and the kernel version in your Ubuntu release.

If they are compatible, download the driver for Linux-based systems.

Also you can start `airdriver-ng` in the a graphical terminal window, and follow the manual.

**Good luck** if you going to need `airdriver`.